# Angular-slider on a modal window

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I'm trying to get the angular-slider (http://prajwalkman.github.io/angular-slider/) to work on a angularjs twitter bootstrap model dialogue.  It works fine on the page, but I cant get it to work on the modal window.  Any thoughts? I'm just learing angularjs...

Here is my code:
http://plnkr.co/edit/gBbReA65qoXsXsC0H3Ft?p=preview

Thanks,  Ryan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like that's a known bug.  It's logged here:  https://github.com/prajwalkman/angular-slider/issues/36

If you don't want to wait on them fixing it (looks like their last commit was 4 months ago...) you can look at the slider provided by angular-ui:  https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-slider

Or here's an example of writing your own:  http://ngokevin.com/blog/angularslider/

Answer (score 0):

I created a new slider that allows for multiple sliders and has the capability to be used in a modal window.

https://github.com/enkodellc/angular-multi-slider